# Bootstrap 4: Can I Change the Font Color for the Bootstrap Disabled Class?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4, disabled-input

I'm running version 4.4.1 of the Bootstrap gem. I have a Bootstrap 4 navbar in my Rails app. Here is some of my navbar code.

```
  <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
    <!-- Hidden li included to remove active class from about link when scrolled up past about section -->
    <li class="hidden"> <a href="#top"></a> </li>
    ..........
    <li class="nav-item nav-link"><%= link_to "#{t :link_story}", story_path %></li>
    <li class="nav-item nav-link disabled"><%= link_to "#{t :link_blog}", blog_path %></li>
    <li class="nav-item nav-link disabled"><%= link_to "https://www.facebook.com/xxxxxxxx/", target: "_blank" do %><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i><% end %></li>
    <li class="nav-item nav-link disabled"><%= link_to "https://twitter.com/lightbecorp", target: "_blank" do %><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i><% end %></li>
  </ul>
```

The disabled class works great. You can't click on them at all which is what I want. I want those links to be gray.

Here is the CSS code. The last line is my attempt to change the font color.

```
.navbar-custom { padding: 0; border-bottom: 0; letter-spacing: 1px; background: $navBackColor; text-transform: uppercase; }
.navbar-custom .navbar-brand { text-transform: capitalize;  }
.navbar-custom .navbar-brand:focus { outline: 0; }
.navbar-custom .navbar-toggler { color: #eee; font-size: 129%; border-radius: 2px; padding: 0 4px; }
.navbar-custom .navbar-toggler:hover, .navbar-custom .navbar-toggler:focus { background-color: #e75926; color: #ffffff; }
.navbar-custom .navbar-brand .navbar-toggler:focus, .navbar-custom .navbar-brand .navbar-toggler:active { outline: 0; }
.navbar-custom a { color: $linkColor; font-weight: bold; }
.navbar-custom i.fas { color: $red; font-weight: bold; }
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav li a { -webkit-transition: background .3s ease-in-out; -ms-transition: background .3s ease-in-out; -moz-transition: background .3s ease-in-out;  transition: background .3s ease-in-out; }
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav li a:hover { outline: 0; color: $linkColorHover; background-color: transparent; }
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav li a:focus, .navbar-custom .nav li a:active { outline: 0; background-color: transparent; color: $linkColorHover; }
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav li.active { outline: 0; }
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav li.active a { background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.3); }
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav li.active a:hover { color: $linkColorHover; }
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav li .disabled { color: $grayDisabled; }
```

I have also tried the following but none of them worked.

```
.navbar-custom .disabled { color: $grayDisabled; font-weight: bold; }

.navbar-custom a { color: $linkColor; .disabled { color: $grayDisabled; font-weight: bold; } font-weight: bold; }

.navbar-custom .navbar-nav li a.disabled { color: $grayDisabled; }

.navbar-custom a.disabled { color: $grayDisabled; font-weight: bold; }
```

All the information I have found is related to Bootstrap 3 where you had to code `pointer-events: none;` in your CSS stylesheet. The .disabled class uses `pointer-events: none;`.

I want to use classes .nav-item and .nav-link to keep those items the same styling as the working links except for the font color.

I didn't see anything in the documentation that says I can't change the font color of the class.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the last line to

```css
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav li.disabled a { color: $grayDisabled; }
```